# Trying to create a for loop to display hash symbol from 1 (#) to 8 (#)

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm currently reading a book that is challenging me to solve some c++ problems. I was able to solve a problem that wanted me to display (#) from 8 symbols down to one. I was able to accomplish this with the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < (8 - i); j++) {

        cout << "#";

    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

However, now I am trying to count up, going from one (#) to 8 (#); pretty much the opposite of the first problem.

Comment: Tip: you can use `i--` to decrease one if you start counting from 8.

Comment: `for (int i = 7; i  >= 0; --i) {...}`?

Comment: Or how about `for (int j=8-i; j>0; --j) { ... }`. You wanted this to go from 8 down to 1, right?

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm still new to this stuff and you all had helpful info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. One way is to set `i` increasing from `0` to `7` and let `j` increase to be less than or equal to `i + 1` every iteration. i.e. (code untested)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    for (int j = 1; j <= i + 1 ; j++) {

        cout << "#";

    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {

        cout << "#";

    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers here, let's not forget the very convenient `std::setfill` command from [`iomanip`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/):

```
#define FILL_CHAR '#'
#define COUNT 8

std::cout << "Count up\n";
for (size_t i = 1; i <= COUNT; ++i)
{
    std::cout << std::setfill(FILL_CHAR) << std::setw(i);
    std::cout << FILL_CHAR << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "Count down\n";
for (size_t i=0; i<COUNT; ++i)
{
    std::cout << std::setfill(FILL_CHAR) << std::setw(COUNT-i);
    std::cout << FILL_CHAR << std::endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1af53c9e2ca802c2)

#### Output

```
Count up
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
########
Count down
########
#######
######
#####
####
###
##
#
```